# Why does FindInstance find a wrong instance to this problem?

Tags: equation-solving

When I ask for an instance in a six-variable problem, Mathematica [version 9] returns an instance that is wrong. (Both of the first two equations are `False` under the substitution.)

```
FindInstance[
 {
  4 k + b + 2 c + d + 4 j == 4 n,
  k + (2 k + b) c + j == n^2/2,
  k >= 1,
  b >= 0,
  c >= 1,
  d >= 0,
  j >= 1,
  n >= 1,
  c + 2 <= n - 2,
  2 k + b <= n - 2,
  n <= 100,
  b == d
  },
 {k, b, c, d, j, n},
 Integers
 ]
```

This returns `{{k -> 4, b -> 1, c -> 8, d -> 1, j -> 4, n -> 12}}`. However, neither of the first two equations is satisfied by this substitution. It is the first time I have ever received a wrong instance from FindInstance. Is this common behavior?

Note also that when I appended the equation `n == 12` to my original system, Mathematica returned a correct instance. This was strange, inasmuch as the wrong instance already had `n -> 12`.

---Adding screenshots---

Here is the original run:

[image: Original run that produced the behavior]

Following the suggestion in the comments, I quit Mathematica, restarted, and tried again. This led to the same incorrect instance:

[image: After quitting and reopening, same behavior results]

I then restarted my computer, opened Mathematica, and tried again. Same behavior:

[image: After restarting computer, same behavior]

Comment: Let sol be the answer to your FindInstance... then {4 k + b + 2 c + d + 4 j == 4 n, k + (2 k + b) c + j == n^2/2, k >= 1,
   b >= 0, c >= 1, d >= 0, j >= 1, n >= 1, c + 2 <= n - 2, 
  2 k + b <= n - 2, n <= 100, b == d} /. sol yields all Trues.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. On my end, {4 k + b + 2 c + d + 4 j == 4 n, k + (2 k + b) c + j == n^2/2, k >= 1, b >= 0, c >= 1, d >= 0, j >= 1, n >= 1, c + 2 <= n - 2, 2 k + b <= n - 2, n <= 100, b == d} /. {{k -> 4, b -> 1, c -> 8, d -> 1, j -> 4, n -> 12}} yields {{False, False, ...}}. With the instance Mathematica returned, the left-hand side of the first equation equals 4(4) + 1 + 2(8) + 1 + 4(4) = 50, while the right-hand side is 4(12) = 48.

Comment: You are correct that `{k -> 4, b -> 1, c -> 8, d -> 1, j -> 4, n -> 12}` does not satisfy the set of equations and inequalities.  However, when I run the code in you question,` FindInstance` returns `{{k -> 4, b -> 0, c -> 8, d -> 0, j -> 4, n -> 12}}`, which is not the list of rules given in your question.  Try running your code again in a fresh instance of Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this and expected it to work, but it didn't (cf. screenshots that I have added to the question). For context, my version of Mathematica is getting pretty old, 9.0.1.0. Maybe it is a bug fixed later? (The documentation in my version doesn't cite any "Possible Issues" - I had checked this before asking my question.)

Comment: Can't reproduce it in  both version 7 ({{k -> 4, b -> 2, c -> 8, d -> 2, j -> 4, n -> 12}}) and version 12 ({{k -> 4, b -> 0, c -> 8, d -> 0, j -> 4, n -> 12}}).

Comment: @user64494 OK so what I'm seeing is that neither of the instances in your comment is the same as the one I got in version 9, and also that the version 7 instance you obtained is incorrect while the version 12 instance is correct. I guess it is really just time to upgrade (I say this frequently).